# How to differentiate between SQL Null ints in c# linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In MVC we can declare nullable ints in our database context models as

```
public int? SomeField { get; set; }
```

But how do you check if a record for SomeField is Null in Linq. For example if I want to get a list of rows with value not zero I use the following Linq statement.

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => u.Somefield != 0 )
```

Is there a Linq equivalent to include/exclude either/both Zeros and Null?

**Edit:** I am currently testing this but I am sure it will either be Null exception or Null fields return as zero.

Comment: Are you talking about null in SQL - the `DBNull` - or are you talking about a .NET null?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I need to check for DBNulls and then translate that into my class accordingly to prevent Null exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would prefer to filter out the `null` values in my data layer to prevent this kind of `null` checking in code.

BUT, you could use:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where(u => u.Somefield.HasValue && u.SomeField != 0)

//Or

var k = db.TableSet.Where(u => u.Somefield != null && u.SomeField != 0)

//Or

var k = db.TableSet.Where(u => u.Somefield.GetValueOrDefault() != 0)

//Or

var k = db.TableSet.Where(u => (u.Somefield ?? 0) != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => u.SomeField != null && u.Somefield != 0 )
```

or for a nullable type:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => u.SomeField.HasValue && u.Somefield != 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes; just compare to `null`.

If you want to exclude both, you'll need an *and* clause.

Comment: The problem with this Int types are not nullable in C#

Comment: @Flood: Your model should closely match your DB model. If it's possible that a column can be `null`, you need to make sure your model's corresponding property can be `null` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => u.Somefield.HasValue && u.Somefield.Value != 0 )
```

Or this:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => u.Somefield != null && u.Somefield != 0 )
```

Or possibly this:

```
var k = db.TableSet.Where( u => (u.Somefield ?? 0) != 0 )
```

Comment: LINQ providers may choke on the second option.

Comment: Unbelievable, almost the same answer!